# Enviar valor de una variable de un metodo a otro javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

hola tengo los siguientes metodos en javascript:

```
function buscarC(consulta) {
var result = "";
var buscado = "";
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/tesisv2/webresources/generic/buscarxC?courseDisplayName=' + consulta['idCurso'] + '&page=1&row=' + consulta['row'],

    success: function (data) {
        var t = "";
        t = data.total;
        initpaginacion(t);            
        var nump;
        var n = consulta['row'];
        nump = Math.round(t / n);
        console.log(f);


        for (i = 0; i < data.elementos.length; i++) {

            buscado = '<tr class="recurso"><td>' + data.elementos[i][0] + '</a></td><td>' + data.elementos[i][1] + '</td><td>' + data.elementos[i][2] + '</td><td>' + data.elementos[i][3] + '</td><td>' + data.elementos[i][4] + '</td></tr>' + buscado;


        }

        result = '<style>table, th, td {  border: 1px solid black;}</style><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"><thead><tr><th>Curso</th><th>IdEvento</th><th>Evento</th><th>Organizacion</th><th>PaisIP</th></tr></thead><tbody>' +
                buscado +
                '</tbody></table>';
        $("#contenido").html(result);
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
}


function initpaginacion(resultadototal) {
if (total % numxpagina == 1) {
    totalpaginado = Math.trunc(resultadototal / numxpagina) + 1;
} else {
    totalpaginado = Math.trunc(resultadototal / numxpagina);
}
if (totalpaginado <= 0) {
    var paginado = "";
    document.getElementById('paginado').innerHTML = paginado;
} else {
    if (totalpaginado == last) {
        var paginado = "";
        paginado += '<ul class="pagination">';
        for (var i = init; i <= last; i++) {
            paginado += '    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;" id="pag' + i + '" onclick="buscar(' + false + ',' + i + ',' + numxpagina + ",'" + 'results' + "'" + ',null,this);"">' + i + '</a></li>';
        }
        paginado += '</ul>';
        document.getElementById('paginado').innerHTML = paginado;
    } else {
        var paginado = "";
        paginado += '<ul class="pagination">';
        for (var i = init; i <= last; i++) {
            paginado += '    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;" id="pag' + i + '" onclick="buscar(' + false + ',' + i + ',' + numxpagina + ",'" + 'results' + "'" + ',null,this);"">' + i + '</a></li>';
        }
        paginado += '    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="next()">&raquo;</a></li>';
        paginado += '</ul>';
        document.getElementById('paginado').innerHTML = paginado;
    }
}
}

function buscar(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
alert(f.text);

}
```

Quiero obtener el valor de la variable f  como se ve en el metedo buscar (con una alerta que indica su valor), para utilizarlo en el metodo buscarC, como puedo obtener ese valor para poder usarlo en el metodo buscarC.

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes utilizar variables globales para que la función buscarC tenga la respuesta de f, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
var mensaje = “Mensaje de prueba”;


function muestraMensaje() {
  alert(mensaje);
}
```

Para tu caso debes declararlas como globales

```
var a, b, c, d, e, f;
function buscarC(consulta) {...}
function buscar(a, b, c, d, e, f) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías generar una variable global (que no estuviera dentro de ninguna función) y asignarle el valor de `f` a dicha variable en la función `buscar`.

```
var dato = "";

function buscar(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
   dato = f.text;
}
```

Y entonces podrás utilizar esa variable `dato` en la función `buscarC`.

```
function buscarC(consulta){
     //Tu código
     console.log(dato);
}
```

Comment: trate eso sin embargo el resultado que tengo es " f is undefined"